Galaxies rotations speeds questions
We accept epic gravitational lensing effects around invisible supermassive black holes, but do we consider possible gentle lensing effects in huge galactic structures observations ? Do we take time and length dilation into account when observing galaxies rotations ?
(this question is not about gravitationnal lensing stretching the light of bodies or structures around or behind a galaxy, it is about lensing effect on a galaxy itself)
A simple observer setting is described in the animation here. If we consider the cone of light (or any wave) converging from a galaxy, like a projected image, toward the center of a distant observer’s eye, the cone does not stretch through space in the same way depending on the observed galactic orbital region, but all regions are simultaneously seen by the observer's eye. The animation is a theoretical schematic description where only the white cone doesn't undergo dilation, nor contraction.
Is this taken into account with some sort of "lens" correction?
If I understand it well, theorical expected values are calculated combining tidal parameters and newtonian principles. Then, observed galactic rotations most often reveal orbital speeds that seem too high, sometimes too slow near the core and too fast on the outside. This is illustrated in a second animation here: theorical values are the white orbiting points, observed data are the blue orbiting points. On the outside, blue points catch on white ones. Now if we apply a "lens" correction, with a focal on the fourth unitary circumference here, angular rotation speeds are identical but radii change the apparent circumference length, and thus the apparent local speed : with proper “lens” correction settings, observations could trivially fit theory.
I also wonder about $v^2=\frac{2GM}{R}$: it can not be the same for two observers undergoing a different time dilation factor, am I wrong? How does a local observer in the gravitationnal field measure R: according to the length of the circumference he is traveling on or to a theorical distance to the Schwarzschild surface?

The orbital velocities of stars and dust in galaxies are well within the Newtonian regime. Neither special nor general relativity play much of a role there, but the galaxy as a whole does cause weak lensing on objects behind it. The dark matter problem arises from the fact that the redshifts expected from the orbital motion do not agree with those that should follow from the estimated Newtonian gravity of the visible matter distribution. The "lens correction" that you can get from GR would be orders of magnitude too small to account for the observed effects.
